# Trying to read data from the body of ActionAsPdf (Rotaviva) to get pdf bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, pdf-generation

I have a method which is used to call the appropriate ActionResult based on the part. This calls the Action method on the asp.net controller to return a view as pdf bytes.

```
private byte[] CreateCertificatePart(string pdfData, CertificatePart part)
    {
        var customSwitches = string.Format(
            "--print-media-type " +
            "--margin-top 10mm " +
            "--margin-bottom 10mm " +
            "--margin-left 10mm " +
            "--margin-right 10mm " +
            "--encoding utf-8 " +
            "--minimum-font-size 11 " +
            "--zoom 1.0 " +
            "--disable-smart-shrinking"
        );            

        var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf(part.ToString(), new { pdfData }) { CustomSwitches = customSwitches };
        var pdfBytes = pdfResult.BuildFile(ControllerContext);

        return pdfBytes;
    }
```

This will call the appropriate ActionResult based on the part string, such as

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public ActionResult NewCertificateBody([FromBody]PdfData pdf)
    {

        var reference = "";

        try
        {
            //var vmCert = (vmCert)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(pdfData);

            return View(pdf.PdfBodyName, pdf.CertModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //AppInsightLog.LogError(ex, quoteReference);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "NewCertificateBody");
        }
    }
```

The issue is I want to get an object from the body of ActionResult (PdfData) and not send data in the query string. But how do I tell the method CreateCertificatePart to put the json string pdfData in the body in the first place?

Thank you!

Comment: Another thing.. I wouldnt have to put data in the body if there was a way the ActionResult could see the values of a static class in the controller.. then I could just use the data on that.. but when its published the data set in a static class is null.. because the actionResult does not share the same context as the controller. I also tried putting data in viewbag, tempdata, session etc and it just doesnt get the value from those.. so i am trying to pass it in to the body.

Comment: This has been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50813581/asp-net-actionresult-cant-see-static-data-in-controller