# asp.net ActionResult cant see static data in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I have a simple static class like this

```
public static class pdfDataSingle
{
    public static PdfData pdf { get; private set; }

    public static void SetData(PdfData data)
    {
        pdf = data;
    }
}
```

I set the class first like this in the MVC controller first

```
pdfDataSingle.SetData(pdfData);
```

I have confirmed the data is all there..

I then need to get the bytes from an action result, so first i call

```
 pdf.Add(CreateCertificatePart(CertificatePart.NewStatementOfFact));
```

So this looks like this..

```
private byte[] CreateCertificatePart(CertificatePart part)
    {
        var customSwitches = string.Format(
            "--print-media-type " +
            "--margin-top 10mm " +
            "--margin-bottom 10mm " +
            "--margin-left 10mm " +
            "--margin-right 10mm " +
            "--encoding utf-8 " +
            "--minimum-font-size 11 " +
            "--zoom 1.0 " +
            "--disable-smart-shrinking"
        );

        var pdfResult = new ActionAsPdf(part.ToString()) { CustomSwitches = customSwitches };

        var pdfBytes = pdfResult.BuildFile(ControllerContext);

        return pdfBytes;
    }
```

The action method that gets called looks like this.. but the static data pdfDataSingle is null!

```
public ActionResult NewStatementOfFact()
    {
        try
        {

            AppInsightLog.LogInfo(pdfDataSingle.pdf.Schedule.PolicyNumber, "NewStatementOfFact");
            return View("StatementOfFact", pdfDataSingle.pdf.Schedule);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //AppInsightLog.LogError(ex, quoteReference);
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "NewStatementOfFact");
        }
    }
```

This works fine when I run it locally.. the action results see the data in the the static class (declared outside my controller), but when published to azure they dont.. anyone have any idea why this might be?

Thanks

Comment: So I should have also said, I am trying to get the pdf bytes from a razor view.. if there is a better of doing this without rotaviva I am all ears :) I have a lot of ActionResult methods similar to NewStatmentOfFact and I dont want to call the database again each time.. its a lot of DB work to get all the data for the model, id rather call it once.. store it.. then re-use it for the various action methods or else this will be very slow.

Comment: where did u place this line `pdfDataSingle.SetData(pdfData);`

Comment: I called it in a post method GenerateNewCertificate (another actionResult) this is where I get all the data for the static class and then I call CreateCertificatePart for all the parts.

Comment: I‘m not a pdf guy , but if the static filed is null, there two reason: 1. you get the field before u set it, 2. at some point you set that field to null.    suggestion: if u'r pdf data never change , set it in application startup , if u'r data change per user, do not use static thing.  if u change it per request , then use a instance class; if there are multple step , use should consider `cache` with keys (like session)

Comment: By instance class you mean a singleton? but that is a class with a static member surely. I tried something like Session["pdfData"] = pdfData; and tried to read that but it was also null :/ a session would be best if it worked.

Comment: Ok its hit me... i will serialise the data into a json string and save that to a database.. the read it back in the action methods and de-serialise it.. will be a loooong string

Comment: just curious , Is there multiple instance of your app running (or IIS multiple process model)? that's the only thing that can happen like this.

Comment: Well its a web app using IIS hosted in azure. Good question.. I noticed when i was logging that my action method also called global.asax, that was shortly after I published so I suppose the web app was still starting up. I looked into sessions state options and one of them is a database, so I am doing the same thing pretty much. Static data seems too unpredictable.. the calling another action method loses the httpcontext. it seems thats what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Serialise the data (PdfData) into a json string and save that to a database. You can then read it back in the action methods and de-serialise it.